# ResourceDictionary element or UserControl?

Tags: wpf, xaml, user-controls, resourcedictionary

I have some XAML to draw a logo and I want to re-use this in various other XAML files (it has no UI and requires no code).  The top level of the logo XAML is a `Canvas` item.

To use the logo in other XAML files is it best to define this logo as an element in a `ResourceDictionary` or create a `UserControl`?

This seems easy with a `UserControl`, however I want to load my XAML files in with XamlReader so I would prefer to use resources so that these can be specified within the XAML.  It seems possible to store items such as a `Canvas` in a `ResourceDictionary` but I am not sure how to reference them.

For example, I can define my logo as a `ResourceDictionary` element as follows:

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <Canvas x:Name="LayoutRoot" x:Key="Logo">
        <!-- My Logo -->
    </Canvas>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

But how can I use this `Logo` in my other XAML files - maybe I have got the wrong idea about resources?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution is a VisualBrush.  I can define this in the ResourceDictionary as follows:

```
<ResourceDictionary
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
<VisualBrush x:Key="Logo">
    <VisualBrush.Visual>
<Canvas x:Name="LayoutRoot" x:Key="Logo"> 
               <!-- My Logo --> 
             </Canvas>
```

Then just use this VisualBrush where necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Typically, if you want to make a resource dictionary for this, you'd make a style.  You could then drop a control, and style it with your resource, in any other xaml file you wished.

However, a UserControl would potentially be an easier option, since it would be a simple, reusable element you could drop in anywhere.

Comment: I don't think a style is the way to go my logo is far too complicated to convert to a style (i.e >250 lines of XAML)

Comment: That's find for a style.  If you're worried, though, you could use a user control.

Comment: It's also slightly awkward to add handlers inside a ResourceDictionary that link to the rest of the application while as a usercontrol is business as usual.